# Link to specific record on page in google app maker

Tags: google-app-maker

This might be a random one. I want to create a field that links to a particular record. It needs to be a link to another page which uses the record I am on. I can get the ID for the record, so how do I create a html link to the page with that specific record?

A button won't do because I am adding the link to the comment section based on the type selected on create.

Any ideas?

Thanks :)

Comment: This also needs to be created in a server script too. That's why I'm having so many issues.

Comment: The other possibility is calling a client script from a server script if that's possible?